# combine two lists in a list of dictionaries into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to combine the list of ages of the groups which are having a repeated name...

My code:

```
dic1 = {'g1': ['45', '35', '56', '65'], 'g2': ['67', '76'], 'g3':['8', '96']}
dic2 = {'g1': ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'], 'g2': ['megha', 'varun'], 'g3': ['gaurav', 'parth']}

for key2,name_list in dic2.items():
   for name in name_list:
      if name=='parth':
         for key1,age_list in dic1.items():
            if key1==key2:
               print(age_list)
```

The output is:

```
['45', '35', '56', '65']
['8', '96']
```

I want the output as:

```
['45', '35', '56', '65', '8', '96']
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

there's more pythonic than that, you need to *chain* the lists. Also, no need for so many loops. A one-liner should do.

```
dic1 = {'g1': ['45', '35', '56', '65'], 'g2': ['67', '76'], 'g3':['8', '96']}
dic2 = {'g1': ['akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'], 'g2': ['megha', 'varun'], 'g3': ['gaurav', 'parth']}

import itertools
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dic1[k] for k,v in dic2.items() if 'parth' in v))


>>> result
['45', '35', '56', '65', '8', '96']
```

A variant without `itertools` would be:

```
result = [x for k,v in dic2.items() if 'parth' in v for x in dic1[k]]
```

With a dict of sets instead of a dict of lists:

```
dic2 = {'g1': {'akshay', 'swapnil', 'parth','juhi'}, 'g2': {'megha', 'varun'}, 'g3': {'gaurav', 'parth'}}
```

those turn your `O(N**3)` algorithm into a `O(N)` algorithm (because `in` lookup in a `list` is `O(N)` but `O(1)` in a `set`).

If you have a missing key, just replace `dic1[k]` by `dic1.get(k,[])` or even `dic1.get(k) or []`.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use itertools as mentioned in other answers, or just simplify your own code.
There is no need to have a three layer nested for loop. As python only allows 
unique keys, you could eliminate the innermost for loop like so:

```
output_list = []  

for key, name_list in dic2.items():
    if "parth" in name_list:
        output_list += dic1[key]

print(output_list)
```

As and when you get the required age list which is to be displayed, add it to the output_list with a simple `+=`.
Though the above code is easier to understand, I recommend using itertools.